# BigQuery sql to convert concerted single value to multi row value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data set as follows:

[image]

and I want to convert it as follows using bigquery sql:

[image]

how to do this in sql?

Comment: What is the format of the `val1` `val2` columns on Bigquery? Are they repeated, or simply string fields? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 as id, '[a][b][c]' as val1, 'x|y|z' as val2 union all
  select 2, '[e][f][g]', 'u|v|w'
)
select id, new_val1, split(val2,'|')[OFFSET(val1_offset)] as new_val2
from mytable, unnest(split(trim(val1, '[]'), '][')) as new_val1 WITH OFFSET AS val1_offset
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select id, val1_arr[safe_ordinal(pos)] val1, val2_arr[safe_ordinal(pos)] val2
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest([struct(regexp_extract_all(val1, r'\[(.*?)\]') as val1_arr)]), 
unnest([struct(split(val2, '|') as val2_arr)]),
unnest(generate_array(1, greatest(array_length(val1_arr), array_length(val2_arr)))) pos
```